# How to create notification based on a list of LocalTime?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, arraylist, android-notifications

I have a list of LocalTime I need to loop throw them and return the hour and the minute separately to add them to a notification

When I treat them individually it is possible using getHour() or getMinute() methods but in a list it doesn't work

```
String q = "01:00:00";
String w = "02:00:00";
String e = "03:00:00";
String r = "04:00:00";

LocalTime qq = LocalTime.parse(q);
LocalTime ww = LocalTime.parse(w);
LocalTime ee = LocalTime.parse(e);
LocalTime rr = LocalTime.parse(r);

List<LocalTime> listTimes = new ArrayList<>();
        listTimes.add(qq);
        listTimes.add(ww);
        listTimes.add(ee);
        listTimes.add(rr);


for(int i=0 ; i<=listTimes.size() ; i++) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,listTimes.get(i).getHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, listTimes.get(i).getMinute());
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, listTimes.get(i).getSecond());


         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_reciever.class);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);      
     }
```

And the actual creation of the notification:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    int notificationId = 1;
    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Channel Name";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId, channelName, importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }


    Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,ReaptingActivity.class);

    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_free_breakfast_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("Notificatio Title").setContentText("Notification message").setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId,builder.build());


}
```

the notification when I set it alone without the for loop it works with no problem but when I add the loop for the list it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stop using `java.util.Calendar` and switch to `java.time` entirely.

If you have a list of times and you want to combine them with the current day (I guessed that by your use of `java.util.Calendar.getInstance()`), you can just combine the `java.time.LocalDate` of today with the parsed `LocalTime` to a `java.time.LocalDateTime` and use its possibilities of getting the time in millis:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String q = "01:00:00";
    String w = "02:00:00";
    String e = "03:00:00";
    String r = "04:00:00";

    LocalTime qq = LocalTime.parse(q);
    LocalTime ww = LocalTime.parse(w);
    LocalTime ee = LocalTime.parse(e);
    LocalTime rr = LocalTime.parse(r);

    List<LocalTime> listTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    listTimes.add(qq);
    listTimes.add(ww);
    listTimes.add(ee);
    listTimes.add(rr);

    // find out what day today is and do that outside the loop
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

    // iterate/stream all the parsed times
    listTimes.forEach(time -> {
        // combine the time with today
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(today, time);
        // then convert it to an Instant (choose the offset you need) and get the millis
        long timeInMillis = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                                .toInstant()
                                .toEpochMilli();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_reciever.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                                                                100,
                                                                intent,
                                                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    // use the millis here then
                                    timeInMillis,
                                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                                    pendingIntent);
    });
}
```

Comment: once I change it I get no notification at all

Comment: @AbdallahRizk Which time zone are you in? I made the offset *UTC* in the code, so change it to yours and see what happens.

Comment: Im not sure what to change it to but im in the middle east specifically saudi arabia

Comment: it is Arabian Standard Time which is GMT+3

Comment: Arabia Standard Time or AST has a UTC offset of + 3:00 do you know to fix it @deHaar

Comment: @AbdallahRizk I updated the code in my answer, try it, please... It was just the line that used UTC that got replaced by one that uses the default time zone of the system it is running on.

Comment: I did change it it partially worked well what I want it to do is to notify me based on the list but instead in only notify me based on the last time only which is 4 and it just loop throw the rest.

Comment: @AbdallahRizk sounds like you are overwriting a single alert instead of creating a list of alerts... But that is definitely a different question ;-)

Comment: thank you any suggest from your experts would be appreciate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917122/how-to-create-a-list-of-alert-for-a-list-of-localdate-to-create-a-list-of-notifi