# how to create multi notification based on a list of localtime

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notifications

I want to create several notification based on a local time list. so first I loop throw the list then I change them to millisecond and send them to the notification. based on the current code it only notify me based on the last time and it only loop throw the rest.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String q = "01:00:00";
String w = "02:00:00";
String e = "03:00:00";
String r = "04:00:00";

LocalTime qq = LocalTime.parse(q);
LocalTime ww = LocalTime.parse(w);
LocalTime ee = LocalTime.parse(e);
LocalTime rr = LocalTime.parse(r);

List<LocalTime> listTimes = new ArrayList<>();
listTimes.add(qq);
listTimes.add(ww);
listTimes.add(ee);
listTimes.add(rr);

// find out what day today is and do that outside the loop
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

// iterate/stream all the parsed times
listTimes.forEach(time -> {
    // combine the time with today
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(today, time);
    // then convert it to an Instant (choose the offset you need) and get the millis
    long timeInMillis = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                            .toInstant()
                            .toEpochMilli();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_reciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                                                            100,
                                                            intent,
                                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                // use the millis here then
                                timeInMillis,
                                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                                pendingIntent);
});
}
```

and this is the notification class where the onReceive method on

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    int notificationId = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    String channelId="";

    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

               channelId = "channel-"+notificationId;
        String channelName = "Channel-"+notificationId;

        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId, channelName, importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }


    Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,ReaptingActivity.class);

  //  repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
   //         | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);


    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  //  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,repeating_intent,0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_free_breakfast_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("Water Time").setContentText("Drink Water").setAutoCancel(true);


        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());


}
```

Comment: I think the problem is the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, which updates an existing `PendingIntent` according to [the Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT). Try one of the other flags, maybe `FLAG_IMMUTABLE`.

Comment: I did change it to all the type of the flag but nothing all I get notification only on the last item on the list